# Increase Maximum Memory of 512M?

Tags: memory, anylogic, memory-consumption

I'm trying to simulate a medium size city's traffic and keep surpassing the memory capacity of 512M. Is there anyway to increase the memory? Thank you!!

Comment: Simulate where? Which language, platform, etc.?

Comment: Sorry new to the website. Thought I was in a specific forum.

Comment: Hi @LisbonGuy welcome to SOF. Some resources to help you understand this place: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this article focussed on AnyLogic: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you @Benjamin I'll be more carefull in the future. And thank you, I've just started to use Anylogic and your videos have been very usefull.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the maximum memory by going to your simulation properties as shown below:

[image]